# How to get Country from value of the key Location?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk, stackexchange-api, geopy

I am trying to add a new key called Country. My main problem is to convert the location into Country. The Users from Stackoverflow can write everything and it has no format. I have tried geopy but it doesn't detect some countries for `Russia` or `Tokyo` as a state.

The second problem is that geopy doesn't allow many requests. I have around 8 million Users.

That Code is just an edit version:

```
def geopytesting(testing, user):
    from geopy import Nominatim
    
    try:
        geolocator = Nominatim()
        location2 = geolocator.geocode(testing)
        print(location2.address)
    except BaseException:
        print("Error")

geopytesting("Russia",None)
geopytesting("Hamburg",None)
geopytesting("Madrid",None)
geopytesting("Omaha",None)
geopytesting("Berlin",None)
geopytesting("Schleswig-Holzstein",None)
geopytesting("Asyż",None)
geopytesting("",None)
geopytesting("Tilted Tower",None)
```

I hope you can Help me. I really try many things and I haven't seen a post which handle this specific problem.
Either it detect some countries or I get kicked out because I made too many requests.

Comment: For starters, don't call `geopy` for every value.  Your app should have/build a sizeable map of strings to locations -- bonus points of you use machine learning.  This will greatly cut down on the requests needed to geopy.

Comment: Have you any source or example for me?